# passing a variable as a parameter and not effecting it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

some times in typescript when i pass a variable as a parameter in a function and modify it in the function the original variable also modify can any one explain to me what's happening

```
let mybrew :any[] = [
    {
        id:5,
        materials:[-1,-1,-1,-1],
        price:16
        },

]
console.log(mybrew);
function bestBrew(abrow:any[]){
    abrow.forEach(
        e=>{
            for (let i = 0; i < e.materials.length; i++) {
            e.materials[0] += e.materials[i];
            }
        }
    )
}
bestBrew(mybrew);
console.log(mybrew);
```

output

```
[ { id: 5, materials: [ -1, -1, -1, -1 ], price: 16 } ]
[ { id: 5, materials: [ -5, -1, -1, -1 ], price: 16 } ]
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're facing?

Comment: i don't  want the variable in the global scoop (mybrew) to change

Comment: So if you do not want the variable in the global scope to change you have to clone the parameter's value that you are passing into the function.

Comment: Since it's an array that you want to pass in, just do `newBrew = Array.from(abrow)` and pass in `newBrew` . Read about pass by value and pass by reference. That'll help.
`

Answer (score 1):

You can do some deep clone on the object.

```
lent newbrew = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mybrew));
bestBrew(newbrew);
```